# Recursive Prolog function with extraneous false solution

Tags: prolog, solution, prolog-toplevel

I'm struggling to understand why `fib([1,2],F)` finds a second solution, false, with the following clauses and rules:

```
fib([A,B|C],F) :-
   fib([B|C],S),
   fib(C,T),
   F is (S+T).
fib([A],1).
fib([],0).
```

According to my logical analysis of `fib([1,2],F)`, I should just be getting the result `F = 2`. I need some help to understand why Prolog finds a second solution, which is `false`.

Comment: What exactly do you want fib/2 predicate to do ??

Comment: I don't think there is a second answer. If you're getting the first answer and then manually asking prolog to give you a second one, it responds with `false` to say there are no other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but I don't understand what your logical analysys can be.

I can say that, from your code, with `fib([1,2], F)` I get only `F = 1`, not `F = 2`; and it's because `fib([1,2], F)` become

```
fib([1,2],1) :-
  fib([1],1),
  fib([],0),
  1 is (0+1).
```

`false` isn't a second solution but (if I'm not wrong) a failed attempt to obtainig (via backtracking) a second solution.

Comment: That's exactly right. When the toplevel says `false`, it means that there are no further solutions.